# Laravel merge relations one table

Tags: php, laravel, relational-database

I have a model **User**. It has 2 relation methods.

```
 public function destinationTransaction()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Transaction::class,
            Account::class,
            'object_id',
            'destination_id'
        )->where('object_type', User::class);
```

And:

```
public function sourceTransaction()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            Transaction::class,
            Account::class,
            'object_id',
            'source_id'
        )->where('object_type', User::class);
    }
```

The difference between them is only in **secondKey** (destination_id and source_id)

I want to create method **transactions** which will return the result `sourceTransaction` and  `destinationTransaction`.

**Example:**

```
public function transaction()
{
    $desTrn = $this->destinationTransaction;
    $srTrn= $this->sourceTransaction;

    // Merge collections and return single collection.
    return $competitionsHome->merge($srTrn);
}
```

This method is not suitable because it returns an array.

Maybe you can somehow write a query with joins?

Comment: not really clear, your `transaction()` method return the collection with `destinationTransaction` and `sourceTransaction`, that not what you want?plz explain the result so we can help.

Comment: I need to combine 2 relations into one

Comment: do u mean all both relationship's attributes in one object?

Comment: Yes, Help me please

Comment: what about the id, they are from different table and all named id, do u want to make the different name, or choose one?

Comment: only choose one.

Answer (score 0):

Try union in your `transaction()` method (untested):

```
public function transaction()
{
    return $this->destinationTransaction()->union($this->sourceTransaction()->toBase());
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have arror
SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1222 The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: That means the two statements in the Union are trying to `select` different number of columns. Please provide the actual SQL query from the query log or from the stack trace. 

Comment: "(select * from `transactions` inner join `accounts` on `accounts`.`id` = `transactions`.`destination_id` where `accounts`.`deleted_at` is null and `accounts`.`object_id` = ? and `object_type` = ?) union (select * from `transactions` inner join `accounts` on `accounts`.`id` = `transactions`.`source_id` where `accounts`.`deleted_at` is null and `accounts`.`object_id` = ? and `object_type` = ?)"


Help me please =)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `users` has many `accounts` by `object_id`, and `accounts` has many `transactions` by `source_id` or `destination_id`, and you want to merge these two into one.

You can use `join` to connect them:

```php
public function transaction() {
    return Account::join('users', 'users.id', 'accounts.object_id')
            ->where('accounts.object_id', $this->id)
            ->where('accounts.object_type', User::class)
            ->join('transaction AS destination', 'destination.id', 'accounts.destination_id')
            ->join('transaction AS source', 'source.id', 'accounts.source_id')
            // Now you can select the destination's columns and source columns with alias names:
            ->selectRaw('destination.*, source.column AS source_column, ...')
            ->get()
}
```